# Create a tester program for c?

Tags: c, testing, executable

I have to create a tester program for  a C project (codetester.c).  The user calls the program by executing:

codetester

or

codetester filename

How do I set up my project so that these commands can be executed?

Comment: Which IDE/toolchain are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your main function like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

`argc` holds the number of arguments, this will be 2 for "codetester filename". 
`argv` holds an array of char sequences; `argv[0]` will be "codetester" and `argv[1]` will be "filename".

Answer (score 2):

Command line arguments are passed through `argv` and `argc`. They are parameters in the main function. So an example would be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1) { //The program name is argv[0]
        printf("We got a filename: %s\n", argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("We did not get a filename\n");
    }
}
```